Timestamp triggered notifications to app?
I'm building a Flutter app that uses Supabase as the backend.  One aspect of the app requires that a server-side process check to see if certain actions are required at a specific date/time. What I'd like to do is have a server side actor push notifications to the Flutter app.
However, Supabase's platform doesn't yet have a notifications feature. Do you have any suggestions on how I might tackle this?

You could use OneSignal, afaik, they even offer a free-tier with unlimited mobile push messages and they integrate in supabase.
